# bst height algorithm in c#

Tags: c#, algorithm, binary-search-tree

```
class node
{
    private float data;
    private node left;
    private node right;

    public int TreeHeight(int depth)
    {       
        root vL = left;//access to left data
        root vR = right;

        return depthOfTheTree;
    }
}
```

The tree looks like that : https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EKan.jpg

Hello, i'm doing on one method algorithm that returns height of the tree.
The method can only access to left and right node. Variable depth as parameter already comes with value 1 to the method itself(counting root of the tree).
i have tried with recursive calling method but the result was not near the expected.
My previous code is similar to code below.

```
public int TreeHeight(int depth)
{
    if (left != null && right == null)
        return left.TreeHeight(depth);
    else if (left == null && right != null)
        return right.TreeHeight(depth);
    else
        return left.TreeHeight(depth) + right.TreeHeight(depth);
}
```

Comment: you should format your code.

Comment: Well I did format his code, then the OP went backwards in formatting.  OP, please format your code properly so its easy to read.

Comment: i did it now @Amy

Comment: Try to put some example on which you tested it and what results you get. What does `depth` do? What is `smth`? The best way to find out what is wrong with it is to make some easy example and debug the code step by step. Make for example 3 node tree (root with 2 children) and try it.

Answer (score 3):

By [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)#Terminology):

> The height of a node is the number of edges on the **longest path** between that node and a leaf.

For BST it can be expressed recursively as (pseudo code):

```
height(node) =  
{
    0, when node == null  
    1 + max(height(node.left), height(node.right)), when node != null  
}
```

Hence the recursive method does not need a `depth` parameter and could be like this:

```
public int TreeHeight()
{
    return 1 + Math.Max(
        left != null ? left.TreeHeight() : 0,
        right != null ? right.TreeHeight() : 0
    );
}
```

and with C#6 [null conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx), the implementation could be simple as that:

```
return 1 + Math.Max(left?.TreeHeight() ?? 0, right?.TreeHeight() ?? 0);
```

Comment: i found lot of examples compared to second code but i have to use number depth as a parameter in method TreeHeight :\

Comment: @MarkoŠkrilec: `but i have to use number depth as a parameter in method TreeHeight` Information like this must be in the question, not hidden in a comment to an answer to the question *as posted*. If you recognise the edit would invalidate answers already posted, don't change the question: ask as new one. If you are convinced neither the old question nor any of the answers are useful, delete it. (You may take a negative score as a hint.)